# Quotient of $k$-algebra by a maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, modules

If $k$ is a field, and $A$ a $k$-algebra which is finite dimensional as a k-vector space.  Are we allowed to say that for a maximal ideal $m$ the field $A/m$ is isomorphic to $k$ or not necessarily? If not, does $A/m$ have some special relationship with $\bar{k}$?

Comment: Whether anyone is "allowed" to say it has nothing to do with whether or not it's true; it's either true or it's false, and of course it's false in this case because $A$ could itself be a nontrivial finite extension of $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $K/k$ is a finite field extension, then $K$ is naturally a $k$-algebra and, of course, finite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space. However, since $K$ is a field, the unique maximal ideal of $K$ is $(0)$ and the quotient field is $K$ itself. Converseley, in general, $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite field extension of $k$ and as such embeds into $\overline{k}$.

Comment: Why is $A/m$ a finite field extension of $k$?

Comment: Is it because $A$ can be embedded as a subring into $\bar{k}$ so $A/m$ can be embedded into $\bar{k}$ as a field? Something like that?

Comment: It is a field, because the quotient of a ring by a maximal ideal is a field. It has finite dimension over $k$ since it is quotient of $A$, which has finite dimension over $k$. This conclusion still holds in case we only assume $A$ to be a finitely generated $k$-algebra rather than a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space, which is the nontrivial Zariski lemma Alex mentions.

Comment: @Thorgott oh whoops, good call. That's what I get for not reading the original post carefully enough. Deleting... :)

Comment: Wait, so the non trivial part is that it's a finite field extension. But the fact that it's a field extension is not that hard. Right?

Comment: No, that's nontrivial under weaker hypothesis. Under your strong hypothesis, all of it is immediate. I'm happy to elaborate further if you tell me which part isn't clear.